# I can't see a VM running using Asustor NAS VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, nas, asustor

I am using Asustor NAS VistualBox to run a VM.

All the software is up to date.  But when I start the VM, I saw the "Preview" of the VM, asking me to install it.

But this preview is like 100 x 100px wide and tall, and I cannot interact with it.

How do I interact with it. Do I use the Asustor Portal or do I use the "Console" icon at the VirtualBox? I clicked it and it said Adobe Flash not install and I can't even find Flash to install since it is "End of Life". (I don't want to install Flash from a third party website).

Answer (score 0):

the only thing one can do here, at least what I have found out, is to use **RDP** to the VM, which is a setting in VirtualBox, Display, enable server, **Remote Display**, it should be the port 3389 (default) and **Authentication** = *none*.

Then, and that's kind of undocumented, you must use the credentials to *your NAS device*, not to your VirtualBox application on NAS, nor to your VM.